# How to change the direction of the output?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery script that outputs lines from the database, how can I change the direction of the output so my latest news would be at the top and not at the bottom?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var lastid = $("#lastid").val();
    var dataString = 'lastid=' + lastid;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getnewdata.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.newid != "") {
          $('#table tr:last').after(result.newtr);
          $("#lastid").val(result.newid);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: This should preferably be done via the server side query rather than the through client side manipulation.

Comment: You can apply `sort()` logic to the `result` that's returned in the AJAX request. Exactly how you do that would depend on it's contents, which you haven't shown. That said, @Script47 is correct, it would be far better to do this sorting on the server side.

Comment: don't insert after the last element (tr), but before the first.

Comment: agreed with @jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.*** Don't append new records after the last `tr`, but add them before the first `tr`.

***So***

Instead of:-

```
$('#table tr:last').after(result.newtr);
```

Do:-

```
$('#table tr:first').before(result.newtr);
```

***2.*** You need to add `ORDER BY <add autoincremented column name here> DESC` in your `query` also.

Comment: @rtstorm  please check my edited answer 2nd part too

Comment: @rtstorm  glad to help you :):)

Comment: now i noticed that after refresh script load again last row, so now I have double last  record

Comment: Ok so I manage to get things right, but one thing is bothering me when I delete let's say the third row out of 10 rows. The script won't recognize that I deleted row num 3 until I refresh the page. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just [prepending](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) `newtr` to `tbody`

Here is the code:

```
$('#table tbody').prepend(result.newtr);
```

Comment: I try this but did not work. I need manual refresh page and still sorting is ascending.

Comment: @rtstorm How do you bind table with existing data on page load?